# LaTeX Error: Environment snugshade undefined when trying to knit pdf from rmd file

Tags: pdftex, knitr

I have a basic `Rmd` file which looks like this:

````
---
title: "trial"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r trial}
plot(1:10)
```
````

When I try to knit a pdf, I'm getting this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment snugshade undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.127 \begin{Shaded}

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

This is my first time working with TeX and I have no idea what the error means. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Load the `framed` package.

Comment: I see that `framed` is a TeX package. How exactly do I load it? If it was an `Rnw` file, I would add `\usepackage{framed}`, but how would I do it with an `Rmd` file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I know nothing about Rnw nor Rmd files. I figured you had a LaTeX code you could complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been investigating the same problema and finally found a solution in my computer (osx mavericks and sierra). In my case, the problem was that when generating pdf file, pdflatex use a local copy (and old version) of framed.sty  in /Users/jpalma/Library/Tex and /Users/jpalma/Library/texmf folder (my local folder for older mactex versions). I removed those folders (local libraries of newer MacTex version are stored in /Library folder).

In order to discover what framed.sty file are being used, you have to generate .tex file (keep_tex: true), compile .tex file and look in the log file where is the framed.sty file that are used. You have to removed this old local copy.

Hope this solution can be useful.

José

Answer (score 1):

Jose's solution worked for me.  Thank you!  I had to remove two older versions of `framed.sty` before it found and started using the one I just downloaded.  I am working in Linux.  Run the `render()` command at the R prompt with `keep_tex: TRUE` as part of the output, as in:

```
output:
  pdf_document: 
     keep_tex: true
```

Then run `pdflatex yourFilen.tex` to generate the `*.log` file.